# Sharepoint 2010 Deployement Target WebApplication is not working as expected

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010

I have developed a feature using sharepont 2010, feature Scope is "Web", feature Deployment Target is "WebApplication"(Deployement Target has been set throw Package->Advanced->Add->Add Assembly from Project Output->Deployment Target as "WebApplication).

In this feature using "SPWebConfigModification" class updating web.config file.

My concern is below:

1)After deploying it should go to particular "web" since its a "WebApplication" deployemnt but this feature is availabe in all the web apllication in the server, even though if we go to Central Admin->System Setting->Manage Farm solution, we can see this .wsp file has been deployed to particular web application not Globally Deployed. I think this looks strange. My requirement is, the feature should be available in one web application not in all web application. Can somebody point me out pls whats wrong in this or how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the property **[ActivateOnDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms436075%28v=office.15%29.aspx)**  in the feature manifest file, this property ONLY applies to features scoped at Farm and Web Application levels. Any feature (Farm or WebApplication) with that setting set to True will automatically activate on all web applications when you deploy the WSP solution. This property is set to true by default.

Read more about it here:

http://www.sharepoint.bg/radi/post/Activate-on-Default-confusion-and-features-scoped-at-Web-Application-level.aspx

Comment: Luis: Thanks for your reply. I have verified that ActivateOnDefault="False" already has been set but feature is visible to all the Web Application, I want to restrict the visibility in one Web Application.

Comment: Unfortunately that cannot be done, it will be visible to all web applications

Comment: Luis:Thanks for your confirmation but still I have confusion on difference between GAC deployment and WebApplication level deployment.

Comment: They are not related. GAC deployment is just a mean to make your libraries visibles to your feature. Everytime you deploy any feature type as a farm solution (no matter the feature type: web, site, webapp etc) it will allways deploy assemblies in the GAC. The other method is application bin deployment: http://dandeng.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/deploy-dll-to-app-folder-in-sharepoint.html